# jQuery selector context not working within $().find

Tags: jquery, find, this, selector

My question is about "this" (selector context) within the jQuery **$().find** function.

My code below grabs a collection of `li`.
Then uses that collection to "find" an h3.
Then adds a div element after the h3 and attempts to use the **$().data** function to associate the new div element onto the h3 for later use.

Does anyone know why when I run this code the $(this) inside of the data function returns the DOCUMENT and not an `li` from the $posts collection?

```
var $posts = $('#blog ul').children();
$posts.find("h3").after("<div></div>").data("div", $(this).parent().find('div'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you are implying that calling the function `find()` somehow creates a scope. The this context can only be created within a function:

```
function(){
  this // now means the context of this function which might be window
}
```

if it is the case that there will only be 1 h3 in the posts collection you could cache it.
Otherwise you are looking for the `each` method;

```
var $posts = $('#blog ul').children();
$posts.find('h3').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.after('<div/>').data('div', $this.parent().find('div'));
});
```

Comment: thanks Gabriel... at some point i had a .click(funciton(){$(this)}) thrown on the end of this thing and it correctly gave me the scope and i did imply to myself that that the $().data before it should do the same... but now i see that the reason the .click worked was because of the function(){}... thanks!

Comment: happy to help, mark as the answer if you think it's a keeper :)